# aiohttp requests with persistent session take longer vs instant session

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to use persistent session across all requests vs creating & closing new sessions each time I initiate request. It's recommended way in [aiohttp docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/client_advanced.html#persistent-session) and persistent session other advantages per my use case.

The problem is that, persistent session takes much more time than instantly created sessions. I expect that using persistent session should take around same time.

Below is the sample script which demonstrates the problem:

```py
import asyncio
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import Optional

import aiohttp

LINK: str = 'http://google.com'
SESSION: Optional[aiohttp.ClientSession] = None


async def request(link: str, session: Optional[aiohttp.ClientSession] = None):
    if session is not None:
        async with session.get(link) as response:
            return await response.text()
    else:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(link) as response:
                return await response.text()


async def make_session():
    global SESSION

    SESSION = aiohttp.ClientSession()


@contextmanager
def timer(msg: str):
    start_time = time.time()

    try:
        yield None
    finally:
        print(f'{msg} elapsed: {time.time() - start_time}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(make_session())

    persistent_session_futures = [request(LINK, SESSION) for _ in range(10)]
    instant_session_futures = [request(LINK) for _ in range(10)]

    with timer('instant session'):
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*instant_session_futures))

    with timer('persistent session'):
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*persistent_session_futures))

    loop.run_until_complete(SESSION.close())

"""
sample output:
instant session elapsed: 1.0750820636749268
persistent session elapsed: 8.006160020828247
"""
```

Can you please help me in understanding the behavior / possible bug?

These are the versions used in the script:
**Python**:  3.8.10
**aiohttp**: 3.8.1
**OS version**: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

**UPDATE 26.05.2022**:
Dockerized versions output expected results:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install aiohttp

COPY test.py test.py

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

```bash
# python3.8-alpine / aiohttp
instant session elapsed: 0.4182624816894531
persistent session elapsed: 0.4050147533416748

# python3.9-alpine / aiohttp
instant session elapsed: 0.42077016830444336
persistent session elapsed: 0.41016197204589844
```

But running locally, in either versions (using venv) results in instant session are faster - very weird!

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're running? I tested it on my computer and got `instant session elapsed: 0.2039353847503662 persistent session elapsed: 0.13978099822998047`. Python 3.9.7, aiohttp 3.8.1. Looking at your code I see no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks @AndrejKesely for the feedback - really appreciate it! Yes - I'm sure - that's the code :)

I've put code in the docker images & now outputs are as expected, i.e. persistent session is quicker (can't even believe myself :D).

On the other hand, I've tested on 2 different Ubuntu (20.04.4 LTS) machines & results are different - persistent session takes much longer. Please see the update

Comment: The first test was done in Docker. I even ran the test in my host machine (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Python 3.8.10, latest aiohttp and I see the exact results (`instant session elapsed: 0.5182437896728516 persistent session elapsed: 0.36999082565307617`). Something on your configuration seems bad (do you use proxy? inspect environment variables on your host)